# How is the PATH env variable set when opening a BASH shell in Terminal.app on OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, path, terminal

What startup scripts—in the order that they are called—set the `PATH` variable when opening a BASH shell in Terminal.app on OS X?

Comment: Environment variables may also be inherited in this context I'd imagine. It could be further up the process chain unless reset (not just added to). But the closest I come to using OS X is a dead MacBook sitting on a shelf.

Comment: Not totally relevant, but maybe useful, is that you can make a persistent change to the PATH seen by *all* apps using a command like `launchctl setenv PATH`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the culprit. The secret sauce was `/usr/libexec/path_helper` it looks in the file `/etc/paths` and in the directory `/etc/paths.d/`.

First `bash` sources `/etc/profile` which executes the following code:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
    # The above line is the secret sauce, so to say...
    # First is adds default PATH values from the file /etc/paths
    # Then all files in the /etc/paths.d/ directory are read and directories listed
    # in each file (one per line) are appended to PATH
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Next `bash` looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.

Listing these steps out, `PATH` is built as follows:

1. Directories in the file `/etc/paths` are added to `PATH`
2. Directories listed in the files in the directory `/etc/paths.d/` are **appended** to `PATH` — Note, that these are appended versus being prepended.
3. Various `PATH={DIR_2_ADD}:"${PATH}"` statements in my `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` files are prepend `PATH`